# Blank Screen Coming into My website after applying http2

Tags: javascript, php, cloud

I am facing blank page issues into my website, and I am unable to crack it from where is throwing like this. Let me tell you I have developed this website in PHP and it is not by any kind of server issue. There is no message in error log or access log.

Most probably it is happening in India Region. I have confirmed with my foreign colleague they didn't faced this issue. Strange.
May be it is from cloudifier CDN, HTTP2 request,

My website URL : https://www.hozpitality.com/
Please help me.

[Blank Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0imE.png)

Comment: So you have to control your webserver config (apache or nginx or other things) maybe you do not activate the HTTP2 support for this.

Comment: CDN cloudfair already handling http2 support for the same, And I am using apache as webserver.

Comment: Ok so take a look here for apache, you need maybe adjust your configuration : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/howto/http2.html